# Rendertron & <script> tags

Tags: angular, json-ld, rendertron

I started using Rendertron for an Angular 6 app. I noticed it does not render the `<script>` tags. Do you know how to configure it to do so?

The reason I need this is for the JSON-LD markup.

I have the `injectShadyDom` set to true as well; it defaults to false. I didn't know if this would assist at all, although this is more for web components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with updates to the source code.  There is a stripPage() function which removes all script tags.  This function is on line 32 of the renderer.ts file.  With a small hack, I can skip tags with type="application/ld+json".  Time to clean it up, make it configurable, and submit a pull request!

**Origional Function**

```
function stripPage() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('script, link[rel=import]');
  for (const e of Array.from(elements)) {
    e.remove();
  }
}
```

**Modified Function**

```
    function stripPage() {
        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('script, link[rel=import]');
        for (const e of Array.from(elements)) {
            if (e.getAttribute('type') !== 'application/ld+json') {
                e.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```